# Combobox DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I'm having a problem with a combobox. I use databinding to display the content of a list (guinodes). My `UINode` items in the list implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChanged` on name changes. If I change the name of an item the combobox is updated, however `combobox.Text` remains the old value. Also please note that `combobox.SelectedValue.ToString()` contains only the type.

Databinding looks like that :

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=graphCanvas, Path=guinodes}"
```

Answer (score 0):

your combobox SelectedValue or SelectedItem should be the selected UINode item, just take it and get the information you want from it. dont know why you use combobox.Text?

Comment: Yep, but SelectedValue/Item only returns the type `asgl_ui.UINode` and not the node's name.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="SubCategory"  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=graphCanvas, Path=guinodes}" DisplayMemberPath="SubCategoryName" SelectedValuePath="**SubCategoryID**" SelectedValue="{Binding SubCategoryID,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
```

Good Luck